# How to make an object A communicate with B so that B is stored in C and A has only a pointer to B, which can be unsafe

Tags: c++, pointers

For example:

```
class Neuron{
private:
      class Dendrite{
            private:
                 //ctor(Neuron& n){..}
                 Collateral& predecessor;
                 double Weight;
                 //public: getters setters
      };
      class Axon{
            private:
                 class Collateral{
                       private:
                              Dendrite& successor;
                       public:
                              //ctor(Axon& a){..}
                 };
                 List<Collateral> collaterals;
            public:
                 //ctor(Neuron& n){..}
                 void CreateNewCollateral(){
                      Collateral c;
                      this->collaterals.AddByValue(c);
                 } 
      };
      List<Dendrite> dendrites;
};
```

I need an Axon to own a collection of `Collateral`s, because I suppose they are part of it. But also each dendrite in `neuron.list` should have a reference (or a pointer) to a corresponding instance of a Collateral which can belong to a different instance of Neuron. For each instance of Neuron there can be different set of collaterals.
 
The problem is that if I add enough new collaterals into Axon´s list, it will have to enlarge itself by copying its items into a `new` object `O`, `delete` the existing Items from `E` and assign the pointer of the `O` to `E`.
Now all the copied collaterals (in Axon) probably have different addresses than in `dendrites.predecessor`, because there I haven't updated them. I think this may cause a runtime error, am I right? How should I solve it?

Edit:
This is how I have implemented the List::AddItemByValue()

```
long AddItemByValue(const T& item){
    if((this->iLastItem+1)==this->Length){
        T* tmp = new T[Length*2];
        for(long i=0;i<=this->iLastItem;i++){
            tmp[i] = this->element[i];
        }
        delete[] this->element;
        this->element = tmp;
        this->Length *= 2;
    }
    this->iLastItem++;
    this->element[this->iLastItem] = item;
    return this->iLastItem;
}
```

Comment: Show how `List<T>::AddByValue` is implemented. If it's a linked list, it should never need to reallocate space for existing elements when a new one is added. `std::list` doesn't have this problem, for example.

Comment: Good point, I haven't thought of the possibility of implementing List as a linked list. It's exacly how I said, it copies items by value when the list is full, I will use the std::list. ;-)